# Is it ok to have one modal component (not rendered by default) inside each element of a list in vuejs?

Tags: performance, list, modal-dialog, vuejs2

We have several lists of items in our application where each item has a button to open a modal.

The modal is always the same for a given list but the presented information depends on the item.

Right now, I have two solutions:

**1. One single modal per list**

The modal is present only once in the List component

The relevant information is passed from a local variable called "selected" (in the data), to the modal component.
Each item has a button that "selects" the relevant information for the modal.

This first solution brings some weird mechanisms to have dedicated information in the modal.
And I don't really like this approach because it introduces some repetition.

```
// example pseudo markup
<div v-for="item in items">
    <a @click="selected = item"></a>
</div>

<Modal data="selected"/>
```

**2. One modal per item**

The modal is contained inside a component with a dedicated button. It is repeated for each element, but the modal is not rendered until the button is clicked.

This one is really convenient, and I like the fact that we can encapsulate responsabilities in a clean way.

```
// example pseudo markup
<div v-for="item in items">
    <ButtonWithModal :info="item"/>
</div>
```

**Question**

I just wonder if there are any problems of performance that could appear in the future. Or if there is something else that is really wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If the modals are different enough, I think it makes sense to have one modal per component. If it is not rendered, you shouldn't have any perf. problems. No need to prematurely optimize. Easy, understandable code is more maintainable. If you are just rendering a bunch of modals, you shouldn't have any perf problems

Hard to say based since there isn't much info about the kind of data and how different the modals are. Of course you can have different modals and still reuse components:

```
<SomeModal>
  <ModalInputWithErrors v-model="some-data" />
</SomeModal

<AnotherModal>
  <ModalWithWithErrors v-model="another-data"
</AnotherModal />
```

Much more understandable, and you aren't really duplicating code, except for an extra `.vue` file, which can all share generic components, and have specialized ones where needed.

Down the track, you can use [async comoponents](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) which allows you to only load the javascript (in your case, the modal code) when the modal is clicked. That way you can have specific modals for each item, and still have a small bundle - just load the modal code when you need it, maybe when the user clicks an item or mouses over the table.